# Sql query to minus the two tables. What Is wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select table1.t1 from
(
(
select   
         ItemCategory.Name as Category,
         InventoryItems.Name as ItemName,
         sum(SalesItems.Quantity) as Quantity,
         (InventoryItems.Weight*sum(SalesItems.Quantity)) as Weight,
         sum(SalesItems.Amount) as Amount
   from SalesInvoices 
   inner join Sales on Sales.ID = SalesInvoices.SalesID 
   inner join SalesItems on SalesItems.SalesID = Sales.ID
   inner join InventoryItems on InventoryItems.ID = SalesItems.InventoryItemID 
   inner join ItemCategory on ItemCategory.ID = InventoryItems.ItemCategoryID 
   inner join BusinessPartners on Sales.BusinessPartnerID = BusinessPartners.ID
   where SalesInvoices.Date >= '2013-07-1' and SalesInvoices.Date <= '2013-11-7'
   group by ItemCategory.Name,InventoryItems.Name,InventoryItems.Weight
) as t1,
(
select  
        ItemCategory.Name as Category,
        InventoryItems.Name as ItemName,
        sum(SalesAdjustmentItems.AdjustedQuantity)*-1 as Quantity,
        (sum(SalesAdjustmentItems.AdjustedQuantity)*InventoryItems.Weight)*-1 as  
         Weight,
         sum(SalesAdjustmentItems.AmountReturn)*-1 as Amount
 from SalesInvoices 
 inner join Sales on Sales.ID = SalesInvoices.SalesID 
 inner join SalesItems on SalesItems.SalesID = Sales.ID
 inner join SalesAdjustmentItems on SalesAdjustmentItems.SalesItemID = SalesItems.ID 
 inner join InventoryItems on InventoryItems.ID = SalesItems.InventoryItemID
 inner join ItemCategory on ItemCategory.ID = InventoryItems.ItemCategoryID 
 inner join SalesAdustment on SalesAdustment.SalesInvoiceID = SalesInvoices.ID
 inner join BusinessPartners on Sales.BusinessPartnerID = BusinessPartners.ID 
 where SalesAdustment.Date>= '2013-07-1' and SalesAdustment.Date <= '2013-11-7'
 group by ItemCategory.Name,InventoryItems.Name,InventoryItems.Weight
 ) as t2
 )
 as table1
```

What I am doing wrong in this query. 1st query is for Sales and second query is for Sale returns. I want to get the difference of Sales and Returns. But is giving me error.

Thanks

Comment: Your SQL syntax seems to be wrong from what I can see. I don't think you can select how you are trying to select, so my guess is you're on the wrong track.

Comment: Basically I want to minus the result of 1st select and second select. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen is right your query has many syntax errors. By Sql query to minus the two tables do you mean based on few columns say for example Category and ItemName you want to get difference between rest of the column values in a single query?

Comment: Your Sub Queries look as though they will return multiple results which you can't do in SQL.  A Sub Query has to return a single value.

Comment: Thanks @AllanS.Hansen I was on wrong track. Now I solved my problem by just doing Union ALL of both selects and I done some aggregation on result of Union. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL minus operator is known as `EXCEPT` e.g. to find sales that have no invoices:

```
-- Sales minus SalesInvoices
SELECT ID
  FROM Sales
EXCEPT
SELECT SalesID
  FROM SalesInvoices;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older versions,

```
SELECT ID
  FROM Sales 
where not exists(SELECT SalesID  FROM SalesInvoices where sales.ID=SalesID);
```